# Json and android Error

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I'm trying to build a app that will connect to a remote sever in this case local host, the program i wrote so far is trying to log  a user in and depending of thier 'type' a different interface will open. I'm getting some Json parser error probably HTML error. Also some java error in my  AsyncTask. My logcat is below ;

```
02-18 06:57:22.391: E/JSON Parser(1817): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Expected ':' after main at character 6 of {main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\android_connect\selectUser.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\selectUser.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
02-18 06:57:22.391: E/JSON Parser(1817): </table></font>
02-18 06:57:22.391: E/JSON Parser(1817): <br />
02-18 06:57:22.391: E/JSON Parser(1817): <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
02-18 06:57:22.391: E/JSON Parser(1817): <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\wamp\www\android_connect\selectUser.php on line <i>18</i></th></tr>
02-18 06:57:22.391: E/JSON Parser(1817): <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
02-18 06:57:22.391: E/JSON Parser(1817): <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
02-18 06:57:22.391: E/JSON Parser(1817): <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0029</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>252392</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\android_connect\selectUser.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\selectUser.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
02-18 06:57:22.391: E/JSON Parser(1817): </table></font>
02-18 06:57:22.391: E/JSON Parser(1817): {"success":0,"message":"No User found"}
02-18 06:57:22.421: W/dalvikvm(1817): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a24b90)
02-18 06:57:22.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1817): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-18 06:57:22.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1817): Process: com.example.newjudoapp, PID: 1817
02-18 06:57:22.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1817): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-18 06:57:22.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1817):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
02-18 06:57:22.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1817):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
02-18 06:57:22.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1817):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
02-18 06:57:22.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1817):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
02-18 06:57:22.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1817):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-18 06:57:22.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1817):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-18 06:57:22.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1817):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-18 06:57:22.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1817):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-18 06:57:22.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1817): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-18 06:57:22.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1817):     at com.example.newjudoapp.MainActivity$selectUser.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:260)
02-18 06:57:22.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1817):     at com.example.newjudoapp.MainActivity$selectUser.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
02-18 06:57:22.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1817):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-18 06:57:22.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1817):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-18 06:57:22.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1817):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: what is MainActivity.java:260?

Comment: @StefanBeike it's the  System.out.println("check this JSON object  :" + json.toString()); to help me check my json data has been made properly .

Comment: start to call your api from a webbrowser and debug it untli you get valid json, THEN call the API from your android application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a PHP error, which is formatted as HTML. Try to fix the error in the PHP file, it's specified in the logs you pasted (`password` is undefined, on line 18 of selectUser.php).

Comment: Thanks , how about my asyncTask ?

Comment: my stack trace is the log cat it is after the php error